# Show data from Model(Dictionary) in html table using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I am using ASP.Net Razor , ASP.NET MVC and jQuery.

I have a dictionary in Model and a drop down list in html table. What I want is , when I select "ALM" option in drop down list , I want to show some data from dictionary in id="leftValues" using jquery .

My code:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@model Dictionary<string,string>

<style type="text/css">

  #myTable {
    position:absolute;
           top:10%;
           left:30%; 
  }
    #heading {
        text-align: center
    }
    #SelectPlatform {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
            top: 10%;

         }
</style>



<table id="myTable">

        <tr> 
            <th id="heading">  Select Platform   </th>
            <th id="heading"> Available Options</th>
            <th></th>
            <th id="heading"> Selected Options</th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                    <select id="SelectPlatform">
                        <option>Select Platform</option>                      
                        <option>ALM</option>
                        <option>Serena</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                   <div>
                      <select style="text-align: center; text-wrap:normal; width: 110%"; size="20%" id="leftValues" multiple >

                       // Here I want to show data from dictionary 

                      </select>
                    </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div>
                    <input style="width: 100%" type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;"  />
                    <input style="width: 100%" type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div>

                     <select style="text-align: center; text-wrap:normal; width: 110%" id="rightValues" size="20%" multiple >

                    </select>

                </div>

            </td>


        </tr>

</table>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#SelectPlatform").change(function () {

            var textValue = $("#SelectPlatform option:selected").text();
            if (textValue == "Select Platform")
            {
                     // some code
            }
            else if (textValue == "ALM")
            {

              // this is working 

                $("#leftValues").append('<option  value=' + '"NoItem"' + ' >HI I am added </option>');   


                // this is not working 
                $.each(Model, function (key, value) {
                    alert(key);
                    alert(value);
                    $("#leftValues").append('<option  value=' + '"NoItem"' + ' >HI I am also added </option>');
                });


            }
            else if (textValue == "Serena")
            {
               // some code
            }


        });




      }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to move the Model values from the front end to the back end. Javascript cannot read ViewModel values as they are processed on the server. You can write them out into javascript though:

```
<script>
    var dicMap = new Map();

    @foreach (var kv in Model)
    {
        @:dicMap.set(@kv.Key, @kv.Value);
    }
</script>
```

now change:

```
// this is not working 
$.each(dicMap, function (key, value) {
```

Comment: It is showing syntax error at comma in foreach loop. By the way , I have got the logic with the help of your answer. I wrote something like this in if conditon and it worked. 
  
                @foreach(var item in Model)
                
                    @:$("#leftValues").append('<option  value="' + '"@item.Value"' + '">'+ '@item.Value' +'</option>');

Comment: I should have said, code was untested. If my answer helped could you accept it so I get the points for helping?!